# Fulltext with special chars for replace in a json. What's wrong?

Tags: mysql, json, replace, sql-like

I'm not new on fulltext and find / replace searches in MySql, but I cannot understand why at this new attempt I cannot arrive to the desired result.
What I want to do is basically very simple.
I have a standard table, and I want to find / replace a portion of json with another.
The problem is that I cannot even find the portion of text I'm looking for (and of course... I'm sure it's there, beacause I can find it in the dump or just copying my field content in a txt file).
No errors, no results.

The table:
id | jsonData
The field I want to search inside is jsonData, mediumtext.
I want to find this:

> {"id":"sPT","label":"Cost in tech delay","type":"integer","value":0}],

and replace with that:

> {"id":"sPT","label":"Cost in tech delay","type":"integer","value":0},{"id":"program","label":"Program","type":"integer","value":0}],

My attempts...
Simple search:
using ' referring to mySql manual no escape for "

1.

```
SELECT *  FROM `projects` WHERE `jsonData` LIKE '%{"id":"sPT","label":"Cost in tech delay","type":"integer","value":0}],%'
```

using " referring to mySql manual \ escape for "

2.

```
SELECT *  FROM `projects` WHERE `jsonData` LIKE "%{\"id\":\"sPT\",\"label\":\"Cost in tech delay\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"value\":0}],%"
```

And of course replacement, same sintax, no results:

```
UPDATE `projects`
 SET `jsonData` = replace(jsonData, '%{"id":"sPT","label":"Cost in tech delay","type":"integer","value":0}],%', '%{"id":"sPT","label":"Cost in tech delay","type":"integer","value":0},{"id":"program","label":"program","type":"integer","value":0}],%');
```

and of course, using escape, always the same result.
No sintax error, but no results.
If I try to search using shorter sentences I get the expected results... but I really need the whole string to be indentified.

Any idea? 
THANKS

Comment: I removed the fulltext-search tag because `LIKE` is just a string-matching predicate with wildcards. It shouldn't be confused with [fulltext search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 1):

`REPLACE()` patterns don't support wildcards. The `%` doesn't have any special meaning as a wildcard, as it does with the `LIKE` predicate.

MySQL 8.0 introduced a new function, [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) which might be able to do what you intend.

But it's always going to be error-prone work to modify JSON using string-replacement techniques. If you're going to use JSON in MySQL, you should practice using [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html).

Even better would be to forget about using JSON altogether. I haven't yet seen any use of JSON in an SQL database that wouldn't be solved more easily and clearly by defining normal tables and columns.

Comment: *"I haven't yet seen any use of JSON in an SQL database that wouldn't be solved more easily and clearly by defining normal tables and columns."* I know some uses 1) storing application warnings/errors/exceptions as JSON format in a log table.. 2) Handling temporary form data which have multiple steps involved which might be continued on a later time.

Comment: Treating JSON as a blob of text data, not trying to access the structure within using SQL expressions, is pretty okay. Use app code to delve into the structure of the JSON document. But when developers try to use SQL expressions to search or update the elements within JSON arrays and objects, it's error-prone and inefficient. Those are cases where using separate columns and tables would be supported better by SQL syntax.

Comment: i very much agree.. SQL operators like `LIKE` or other string matching function including regex should not be used on JSON data.. Unless you need to write a full JSON parser in SQL which is confirm the JSON grammar if your MySQL version does not support native the JSON functions.. Ouestion is offcource if you want to go in that direction.